# Is this how I should be understanding what a multiway tree is?

Tags: c++, tree, multiway-tree

I  am currently about to implement a multi-way tree in c++, but I am still not sure about what exactly they are. I have read a few documentations, but I am still confused because of the lack of pictures or visualization provided.

Lets say I want a 3 way tree, according to online web notes it means each node can have at most 3-1 = 2 elements and each node can have at most 3 children. Below I have drawn some trees that I am not sure if they are 3-way trees, can someone please verify I am understanding this correctly? Thank you!

Also, if I have a 2 way tree, does that mean I have a binary tree as well? O.o?
[image]

Comment: Looks like your diagram for #2 is a linked list.

Comment: I left the boxes blank because I think we don't have to have m children or m-1 elements per node right?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well yes, you could say it's a linked list, but the question is whether it's also a 3-way tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of a multi-way tree is the number of subtrees that can be traversed from a single node.

```
           +---+  
           | D |
           +---+  
             ^  
             |  
             |  
+---+     +------+     +---+  
| A | <-- | Root | --> | B |  
+---+     +------+     +---+
             |  
             |  
             V
           +---+  
           | C |  
           +---+
```

The diagram above shows a multi-way tree because the root has more than 1 child.

Usually 2 children per node (except leaf nodes) indicates binary trees.
There are many different kinds of binary trees.

See also B-Tree and B*Trees.

**Edit 1:**
Another view:

```
 +------------------------+  
 |          Root          +
 +------------------------+  
  |       |       |       |  
  V       V       V       V  
+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+  
| A |   | B |   | C |   | D |  
+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+
```

Comment: I see, so I am correct in thinking that with a m way tree, I do not require to max out all the available spaces then.